# XSLT/Xpath : matching multiple elements with redundant Xpath starters

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML that look like this :

```
<parent>
    <child1/>
    <child2/>
    <child3/>
    <child4/>
    <child5/>
    <child6/>
</parent>
```

And I have a template that match only specific children looking like this :

```
<xsl:template match="parent/child1|parent/child4|parent/child6/>
```

Is there a way to write the "parent" tag only once and then write the "child" tags in a simplified expression witch would look like this ?

```
<xsl:template match="parent/(child1|child4|child6)"/>
```

Comment: In XPath 2.0 `parent/(child1|child4|child6)` will do exactly what you need. In XPath 1.0 - this syntax is unacceptable

Comment: The syntax would work in a `select` statement, but not in a template match which expects only a "pattern" (Which is only a subset of xpath expressions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139105/using-parentheses-in-xpath-xslt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
<xsl:template match="parent/*[self::child1 or self::child4 or self::child6]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example you could just write this

```
 <xsl:template match="child1|child4|child6"/>
```

You would only need to worry about adding `parent` if there were other `child1` elements in the XML with a different parent that you didn't want to remove. If this wasn't the case, you could instead write this...

```
<xsl:template match="(child1|child4|child6)[parent::parent]"/>
```

EDIT: As mentioned in comments, this only works in XSLT 3.0 and above.

Comment: I think you suggestion `<xsl:template match="(child1|child4|child6)[parent::parent]"/>` is supported in XSLT 3 but not in XSLT 1 nor in XSLT 2.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I had tested it at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHU6, but had the left the processor as Saxon 9.5.1 which gave the impression it worked in XSLT 1.0....